# how to hover featured img in wordpress with ACF

Tags: jquery, wordpress, hover, advanced-custom-fields

I have  code

```
<div class=""/> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>"> <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
            the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class'  => 'img-fluid d-block mx-auto' ) ); // show featured image
        }
```

what I should add to make featured img hover. Hover img should be get from ACF field "imghover"

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your file.

```
<div class=""/> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>"> <?php the_field('imghover');?></div>
```

Comment: I think it will add only hover img inside code. I want feature img and after I go mouse on img I will see hover

Comment: @stecu <?php the_field('imghover');?> is get your "imghover" value from ACF

Comment: for hover(mounce on img) you need to add some css code for hover effects...

Comment: Yes but I want onmouseover and onmouseout functions `<div class=""/> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>">
       <img src="<?php echo  get_the_post_thumbnail($the_query->post->ID); ?>" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto"
     onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo esc_url($hoverimage['url']); ?>'"
    onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo  get_the_post_thumbnail($the_query->post->ID);?>'" />
    </a></div> `